# How to use QProcess::startDetached() combined with setStandardOutputFile()

Tags: c++, qt

I have a process which is supposed to start another process and am using QProcess::startDetached() as there is no relationship to the forked process. Now I am trying to figure out a way to redirect the stdout to a file.
When I use setStandardOutputFile() with QProcess::startDetached() the redirection to file doesn't work. 
While setStandardOutputFile() works fine with QProcess::start().

I thought since QProcess::startDetached() is the static method, it might not work with setStandardOutputFile() but I saw this statement in QProcess documentation,

```
Only the following property setters are supported by startDetached():
setArguments()
setCreateProcessArgumentsModifier()
setStandardOutputFile()
etc.
```

Trying to understand what this statement means in the documentation.

Here is the gist of code,

```
void ForkProcess()
{
    QProcess processObj;
    processObj.setStandardOutputFile("/tmp/stdoutfile.txt");
    processObj.startDetached(processWithArguments);
}
```

This doesn't redirect the stdout to the file while if I use processObj.start(processWithArguments) the redirection works just fine.

Any thoughts on why QProcess::startDetached() doesn't work?

Comment: What platform are you running on? Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [non-static `QProcess::startDetached member](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached)...

```
bool QProcess::startDetached(qint64 *pid = nullptr);
```

The following seems to work fine for me (Suse Linux + Qt5.12.0)...

```
QProcess process;
process.setProgram("ls");
process.setStandardOutputFile("/tmp/stdoutfile.txt");
process.startDetached();
```